# Communicating between applications with socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have an application that needs to send a status log to a server, but I am struggling with sending data.

My code is: (I am using localhost since I don't have another computer for testing for now; in the real case, multiple app will communicate with the server)

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    io = require('socket.io'),
    IP = '',
    PATH = process.argv[1].substr(0, process.argv[1].lastIndexOf('/') + 1); //Path of the app

function log(LOG, message) { //wrapper for console.log, with formatting for my logs
    if(!message) {
        console.log('T-\t' + LOG);
    } else {
        console.log('T-\t' + LOG + :\t' + message);
    }
}

expots.start = function start() {
    log('APP');
    fs.readFile(PATH + 'server', function(err, data) { //PATH/server is a text file, wich contain 'localhost'
        if(err) {
            log('ERROR', 'Can t read ' + PATH + 'server');
        } else {
            setTimeout(function () { //delay for the server to start before trying to connect
                log('timeout end');
                data = '' + data;
                IP = data.substr(0, data.indexOf('\n')); //get IP without \n
                log('IP is', IP);
                var socket = io.connect(); //Don t know if I can put IP here
                socket.emit('data', {m: 'test'});
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the code from the server:

```
function log(LOG, message) {
    if(!message) {
        console.log('S-\t' + LOG);
    } else {
        console.log('S-\t' + LOG + :\t' + message);
    }
}

exports.start = function start() {
    log('SERVER');
    var io = require('socket.io');
    log('Server start');
    io.sockets.on('connection', function socket) {
        log('Connection from', socket);
        socket.on('data', function (m) {
            log('mail', m);
        });
    });
}
```

I start them on the same time with a bash command, and I get multiple errors. I don't know what goes wrong.

Errors are:

server:

```
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
               ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined
    at Object.start
    at process.i
    at process.EventEmitter.emit
    at handleMessage
    at Pipe.channel.onread
```

app:

```
    var socket = io.connect();
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'connect'
    at null._onTimeout
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout]
```

I have socket.io freshly installed from npm. The version of node.js is v0.10.21.

EDIT: socket.io is version 9.16
But I d like to highlight that server do not start app by itself, they are started separatedly, unlike the example which send a html page, it is a self contained node.js app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have installed the 1.0 version which has a different API than 0.9.

The doc on http://socket.io still refers to 0.9, so you have to look at the README on github for the new method signatures : https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io

Comment: It is that, is there a way to get 0.9 version directly? I m new to socket.io and I prefer to have lot of example/docs than just one source when I develop

Comment: sure you can either force the 0.9 version in your package.json or specify it in the npm install version : npm install <name>@<version> https://npmjs.org/doc/install.html

Comment: Ah, I've been to quick to validate, npm downloaded socket.io 9.16 automatically, sorry to reopen the question.